# execute program in various folders sequentially

Tags: linux

I have two folders named `one` and `two`, placed in /home/. There is an (identical) executable `prog.x` in each folder, which takes 1 hour to finish after begin executed. I would like to first execute `/home/one/prog.x` and then `/home/two/prog.x` (so not at the same time).

I would like to make a script that does this for me. Is there a smart way to achieve this? Note that `prog.x` works by loading in a data file, which is located in the same folder.

Comment: Can I get feedback to why my question deserves a thumb down? Seems like the most decent thing to do, right?

Comment: Don't think it was deserved, but you could be clearer about the program only being able to find the data file by its location in the same directory as the executable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your program (unwisely?) has an implicit dependence on its executing directory, you may want to consider using subshells, and a `;` to separate sequential commands

in a `bash` style shell you could do something like:

```
(cd /home/one ; ./prog x) ; (cd /home/two ; ./prog.x)
```

If you want to make a more general solution, you could use a `for` loop over a list:

```
for d in one two ; do cd /home/$d ; ./prog.x ; done
```